# How to set custom icon at left align in the Jquery mobile header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using custom icon in the header, Icon is displaying. But I need to set it in the left side not at center. How to do that,

```
 <div  data-role="header" data-theme="a">
             <h3>
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <img src="img/profileOrange.png">
                    </div>
                    <div id="profileName">My Cards</div>
            </h3>
</div>
```

screenshot  for above code,

[image]

But I need the Icon to be displayed at left side of the header not at center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of float left, use a `class="ui-btn-left"` on the div

**working example** http://jsfiddle.net/h8JFv/16/